# Converting grouped hex characters into a bitstring in Perl

Tags: perl, endianness, pack, bitstring

I have some 256-character strings of hexadecimal characters which represent a sequence of bit flags, and I'm trying to convert them back into a bitstring so I can manipulate them with `&`, `|`, `vec` and the like.  The hex strings are written in integer-wide big-endian groups, such that a group of 8 bytes like `"76543210"` should translate to the bitstring `"\x10\x32\x54\x76"`, i.e. the lowest 8 bits are `00001000`.

The problem is that `pack`'s "`h`" format works on one byte of input at a time, rather than 8, so the results from just using it directly won't be in the right order. At the moment I'm doing this:

```
my $bits = pack("h*", join("", map { scalar reverse $_ } unpack("(A8)*", $hex)));
```

which works, but feels hackish.  It seems like there ought to be a cleaner way, but my `pack`-fu is not very strong.  Is there a better way to do this translation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my $hex = "7654321076543210";  # can be as long as needed
my $bits = pack("V*", unpack("N*", pack("H*", $hex)));
print unpack("H*", $bits);  #: 1032547610325476
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [hex](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex.html) function to turn the hex string into Perl's internal representation of the number, do your bitwise operations, and use [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) to turn it back into the hex string:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $hex = "76543210";
my $num = hex $hex;

$num &= 0xFFFF00FF; # Turn off the third byte

my $new_hex = sprintf("%08x", $num);

print "It was $hex and is now $new_hex.\n";
```

Comment: The solution you propose works only for small numbers, i.e. if $hex is not longer than 8 or 16 bytes.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  I wasn't clear about that in the original question.  It's edited now.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the excellent [Bit::Vector](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Bit::Vector).