# byte swap with perl

Tags: perl

I am reading a file, containing integers using the "33441122" byte order. How can I convert the file to the "11223344" (big endian) byte order? I have tried a few things, but I am really lost.

I have read a lot about Perl, but when it comes to swapping bytes, I'm in the dark. How can I convert this:

```
33 44 11 22
```

into this:

```
11 22 33 44
```

using Perl.

Any input would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are you talking about just doing the switcheroo on an ascii hex-string? `=~ s/([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/$2$1/g` Add spaces if those are actually in there.

Comment: Do you mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853845/converting-grouped-hex-characters-into-a-bitstring-in-perl

Comment: what i would like do do is open the file and swap the bytes then save it as another file.

Comment: You really have an endianness of 3412, not 1234 or 4321? That's rather rare.

Comment: yes, its 34 12 78 56 and i want 12 34 56 78. also @x00 its 16 byte length like this as an example ...  34 12 78 56 34 12 78 56 34 12 78 56 34 12 78 56

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read 4 bytes at a time, split it into individual bytes, swap them and write them out again

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fin, '<', $ARGV[0]) or die "Cannot open $ARGV[0]: $!";
binmode($fin);
open(my $fout, '>', $ARGV[1]) or die "Cannot create $ARGV[1]: $!";
binmode($fout);

my $hexin;
my $n;
while (($n = read($fin, $bytes_in, 4)) == 4) {
    my @c = split('', $bytes_in);
    my $bytes_out = join('', $c[2], $c[3], $c[0], $c[1]);
    print $fout $bytes_out;
}

if ($n > 0) {
    print $fout $bytes_in;
}

close($fout);
close($fin);
```

This will be called on the command line as

```
perl script.pl infile.bin outfile.bin
```

`outfile.bin` will be overwritten.

Comment: i know this sounds like a noob question, but how would i incorporte my file into this code? and then save it as something else? i can do this with python, but perl is a diff kind of monster, and i could use the example :)

Comment: hmm, seems the filesize is larger than the original, and it add a random "0D" at different intervals. but i do have a good idea how it is done now. thatnks alot man :)

Comment: @james28909 Ouch, seems I missed binary mode, sorry. Please see updated answer.

Comment: hell, i should have caught that :O

Comment: and is a very educational :)

Comment: The loop body can be reduced to `print $fout join '', ( split '', $bytes_in )[2,3,0,1];`

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to read two bytes at a time and dwap them before outputting them.

This program creates a data file `test.bin`, and then reads it in, swapping the bytes as described.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use autodie;

open my $fh, '>:raw', 'test.bin';
print $fh "\x34\x12\x78\x56";

open my $out, '>:raw', 'new.bin';
open $fh, '<:raw', 'test.bin';

while (my $n = read $fh, my $buff, 2) {
  $buff = reverse $buff if $n == 2;
  print $out $buff;
}
```

Comment: That gives 44332211 instead of 11223344 for 44331122