# Fast Byte Swap with perl

Tags: perl, byte, swap

I originally asked this question here :[byte swap with perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586336/byte-swap-with-perl)

and i have modified the code, but i found a program that does this same task in .002 secs.
if you look at the link you will see how i have the code modified.
now while this did speed it up a little bit, its still no where near as fast as the other reversing program.
here is the modified code:

```
my $hexin;
my $n;
 while (($n = read($fin, $bytes_in, 512)) == 512) {
        my @c = split('', $bytes_in);
        my $bytes_out = join('', $c[1], $c[0], $c[3], $c[2], $c[5], $c[4], $c[7], $c[6], $c[9], $c[8], $c[11], $c[10], $c[13], $c[12], $c[15], $c[14], 
                              $c[17], $c[16], $c[19], $c[18], $c[21], $c[20], $c[23], $c[22], $c[25], $c[24], $c[27], $c[26], $c[29], $c[28], $c[31], $c[30], 
                              $c[33], $c[32], $c[35], $c[34], $c[37], $c[36], $c[39], $c[38], $c[41], $c[40], $c[43], $c[42], $c[45], $c[44], $c[47], $c[46], 
                              $c[49], $c[48], $c[51], $c[50], $c[53], $c[52], $c[55], $c[54], $c[57], $c[56], $c[59], $c[58], $c[61], $c[60], $c[63], $c[62],
                              $c[65], $c[64], $c[67], $c[66], $c[69], $c[68], $c[71], $c[70], $c[73], $c[72], $c[75], $c[74], $c[77], $c[76], $c[79], $c[78], 
                              $c[81], $c[80], $c[83], $c[82], $c[85], $c[84], $c[87], $c[86], $c[89], $c[88], $c[91], $c[90], $c[93], $c[92], $c[95], $c[94],
                              $c[97], $c[96], $c[99], $c[98], $c[101], $c[100], $c[103], $c[102], $c[105], $c[104], $c[107], $c[106], $c[109], $c[108], $c[111], $c[110], 
                              $c[113], $c[112], $c[115], $c[114], $c[117], $c[116], $c[119], $c[118], $c[121], $c[120], $c[123], $c[122], $c[125], $c[124], $c[127], $c[126], 
                              $c[129], $c[128], $c[131], $c[130], $c[133], $c[132], $c[135], $c[134], $c[137], $c[136], $c[139], $c[138], $c[141], $c[140], $c[143], $c[142], 
                              $c[145], $c[144], $c[147], $c[146], $c[149], $c[148], $c[151], $c[150], $c[153], $c[152], $c[155], $c[154], $c[157], $c[156], $c[159], $c[158], 
                              $c[161], $c[160], $c[163], $c[162], $c[165], $c[164], $c[167], $c[166], $c[169], $c[168], $c[171], $c[170], $c[173], $c[172], $c[175], $c[174], 
                              $c[177], $c[176], $c[179], $c[178], $c[181], $c[180], $c[183], $c[182], $c[185], $c[184], $c[187], $c[186], $c[189], $c[188], $c[191], $c[190], 
                              $c[193], $c[192], $c[195], $c[194], $c[197], $c[196], $c[199], $c[198], $c[201], $c[200], $c[203], $c[202], $c[205], $c[204], $c[207], $c[206], 
                              $c[209], $c[208], $c[211], $c[210], $c[213], $c[212], $c[215], $c[214], $c[217], $c[216], $c[219], $c[218], $c[221], $c[220], $c[223], $c[222], 
                              $c[225], $c[224], $c[227], $c[226], $c[229], $c[228], $c[231], $c[230], $c[233], $c[232], $c[235], $c[234], $c[237], $c[236], $c[239], $c[238], 
                              $c[241], $c[240], $c[243], $c[242], $c[245], $c[244], $c[247], $c[246], $c[249], $c[248], $c[251], $c[250], $c[253], $c[252], $c[255], $c[254],
                              $c[257], $c[256], $c[259], $c[258], $c[261], $c[260], $c[263], $c[262], $c[265], $c[264], $c[267], $c[266], $c[269], $c[268], $c[271], $c[270], 
                              $c[273], $c[272], $c[275], $c[274], $c[277], $c[276], $c[279], $c[278], $c[281], $c[280], $c[283], $c[282], $c[285], $c[284], $c[287], $c[286], 
                              $c[289], $c[288], $c[291], $c[290], $c[293], $c[292], $c[295], $c[294], $c[297], $c[296], $c[299], $c[298], $c[301], $c[300], $c[303], $c[302], 
                              $c[305], $c[304], $c[307], $c[306], $c[309], $c[308], $c[311], $c[310], $c[313], $c[312], $c[315], $c[314], $c[317], $c[316], $c[319], $c[318],
                              $c[321], $c[320], $c[323], $c[322], $c[325], $c[324], $c[327], $c[326], $c[329], $c[328], $c[331], $c[330], $c[333], $c[332], $c[335], $c[334], 
                              $c[337], $c[336], $c[339], $c[338], $c[341], $c[340], $c[343], $c[342], $c[345], $c[344], $c[347], $c[346], $c[349], $c[348], $c[351], $c[350],
                              $c[353], $c[352], $c[355], $c[354], $c[357], $c[356], $c[359], $c[358], $c[361], $c[360], $c[363], $c[362], $c[365], $c[364], $c[367], $c[366], 
                              $c[369], $c[368], $c[371], $c[370], $c[373], $c[372], $c[375], $c[374], $c[377], $c[376], $c[379], $c[378], $c[381], $c[380], $c[383], $c[382], 
                              $c[385], $c[384], $c[387], $c[386], $c[389], $c[388], $c[391], $c[390], $c[393], $c[392], $c[395], $c[394], $c[397], $c[396], $c[399], $c[398], 
                              $c[401], $c[400], $c[403], $c[402], $c[405], $c[404], $c[407], $c[406], $c[409], $c[408], $c[411], $c[410], $c[413], $c[412], $c[415], $c[414], 
                              $c[417], $c[416], $c[419], $c[418], $c[421], $c[420], $c[423], $c[422], $c[425], $c[424], $c[427], $c[426], $c[429], $c[428], $c[431], $c[430], 
                              $c[433], $c[432], $c[435], $c[434], $c[437], $c[436], $c[439], $c[438], $c[441], $c[440], $c[443], $c[442], $c[445], $c[444], $c[447], $c[446], 
                              $c[449], $c[448], $c[451], $c[450], $c[453], $c[452], $c[455], $c[454], $c[457], $c[456], $c[459], $c[458], $c[461], $c[460], $c[463], $c[462], 
                              $c[465], $c[464], $c[467], $c[466], $c[469], $c[468], $c[471], $c[470], $c[473], $c[472], $c[475], $c[474], $c[477], $c[476], $c[479], $c[478], 
                              $c[481], $c[480], $c[483], $c[482], $c[485], $c[484], $c[487], $c[486], $c[489], $c[488], $c[491], $c[490], $c[493], $c[492], $c[495], $c[494], 
                              $c[497], $c[496], $c[499], $c[498], $c[501], $c[500], $c[503], $c[502], $c[505], $c[504], $c[507], $c[506], $c[509], $c[508], $c[511], $c[510]);
        print $fout $bytes_out;
}
```

**EDIT**
This is how i am doing it now. happens in a snap ;)

```
my ($buf, $data, $n, $bytes);

 while (($n = read $infile, $data, 16384) != 0) {
    print $outfile pack("v*", unpack("n*", $data));
    $bytes+=$n;
}
```

using pack/unpack is WAY faster... exponentially even

Comment: why did you manually write it out? you could have used excel

Comment: i guess what i am asking is...  would there be a way to make it happen as fast as this other program. could someone show me a few different options? i would really appreciate it :)

Comment: i manually written out everything after (my $bytes_out=join(

Comment: you could have just excel to do that.

Comment: how would i use excel for this? can you gimme a link or anything?

Comment: did you already know ahead of time the order of $c[3] etc... like 5,2,78,23,78, ? if you already knew it ahead of time then u can easily do it in excel. sorry i'm absolutely baffled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Next time you want to do something like that, use a slice!

```
print $fout join '', @c[1,0,3,2,...];
```

But that's not gonna make much different speed-wise. The following should be much better.

```
print $fout pack 'N*', unpack 'V*', pack 'v*', unpack 'n*', $bytes_in;
```

or

```
$bytes =~ s/(..)(..)/$2$1/sg;
print $fout $bytes;
```

Also, read bigger chunks at a time, such as 64*1024.

---

When dealing with 512 byte strings: ("list" is your original code)

```
         Rate slice  list subst  pack
slice  3100/s    --   -7%  -38%  -86%
list   3327/s    7%    --  -34%  -85%
subst  5038/s   63%   51%    --  -77%
pack  21859/s  605%  557%  334%    --
```

When dealing with 64KB strings:

```
        Rate  list slice subst  pack
list  14.9/s    --   -2%  -60%  -92%
slice 15.2/s    2%    --  -59%  -92%
subst 37.1/s  148%  144%    --  -80%
pack   188/s 1160% 1135%  407%    --
```

Benchmark code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark qw( cmpthese );

my @indexes = map { $_+1, $_+0, $_+3, $_+2 } 0..512/4-1;

my $list = join ',', map "\$c[$_]", @indexes;
my $slice = '@c['.join(',', @indexes).']';

my %tests512 = (
   list  => 'my @c = split //, $str; my $x = join "", '.$list.';',
   slice => 'my @c = split //, $str; my $x = join "", '.$slice.';',
   pack  => 'my $x = pack "N*", unpack "V*", pack "v*", unpack "n*", $str;',
   subst => '$str =~ s/(..)(..)/$2$1/sg; my $x = $str;',
);

my %tests64KB = (
   list  => 'my $x = join "", map { my @c = split //; '.$list.' } unpack "(a512)*", $str;',
   slice => 'my $x = join "", map { my @c = split //; '.$slice.' } unpack "(a512)*", $str;',
   pack  => 'my $x = pack "N*", unpack "V*", pack "v*", unpack "n*", $str;',
   subst => '$str =~ s/(..)(..)/$2$1/sg; my $x = $str;',
);

$_ = 'use strict; use warnings; our $str; ' . $_ . ' 1;'
   for values(%tests512), values(%tests64KB);

{ local our $str = "\x00" x 512;       cmpthese(-3, \%tests512 ); }
{ local our $str = "\x00" x (64*1024); cmpthese(-3, \%tests64KB); }
```

Comment: i tried that but its about the same speed as i have right now :)

Comment: WOW i just did that and it did it really quick, but its not the same file size

Comment: huh? Forgot to `binmode` your handles?

Comment: no, the files both open in binmode just like the in the link. original file is 16384 bytes before and after its 15104 bytes, BUT it is reverse in the correct order. this is how i incorporated it btw: while (($n = read($fin, $bytes_in, 64*1024)) == 512) {

Comment: Get rid of ` == 512`. Why are you checking if you read 512 bytes?

Comment: ok got past the error, but the file size is  still diff. this is what i have now://while ($n = read($fin, $bytes_in, 64*1024)) {

Comment: @ikegami this looks like straight swapping of pairs of bytes, nothing that needs to deal with a 4-byte chunk. Why is `pack "v*", unpack "n*", ...` not enough?

Comment: can i have an example please?

Comment: it is slower than what i already have. i guess there is no quicker way to do it.

Comment: Your code doesn't work. It reads 32KB blocks, but only fixes the first 0.5KB.

Comment: I didn't believe you, so I ran some benchmarks (see update). What you say isn't true. Substitution is a fair bit faster, and `pack` is a whole lot faster! (And not shown in the benchmark is that working with 64KB at a time instead of 512 is crazy faster since you do only 1/128th of the IO calls.

Comment: well any example how i could incorporate that into my code would be greatly appreciated m8 :) i have a file that is 16MB exactly (16384) and all i am trying to do is convert it to 00112233 instead of 11003322. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the way it is now, it will reverse the file, patch it at 3 offsets, then reverse it to original order in 7.2 secs or so.

Comment: You already have the code for IO. The code for IO is the same for all methods.

Comment: `perl -e'binmode(STDIN); binmode(STDOUT); local $/; print pack "N*", unpack "V*", pack "v*", unpack "n*", <STDIN>;' <file >file2` takes 1.370 seconds.

Comment: Surprisingly, doing 64K at a time was faster! `perl -e'binmode(STDIN); binmode(STDOUT); local $/ = \(64*1024); while (<STDIN>) { print pack "N*", unpack "V*", pack "v*", unpack "n*", $_; }' <file >file2` took 1.028s

Comment: original post updated., the way its working now, it happens in .03 secs it reverses, patches then re-reverses it for /use/. see original post for update. thanks :)